# Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later

Tags: boot, systemd

My computer starts in around 40s, but I keep getting this message for 10 minutes:

```
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.
```

After 10 minutes I get this:

```
Startup finished in 6.020s (firmware) + 4.561s (loader) + 3.832s (kernel) + 10min 25.241s (userspace) = 10min 39.655s
```

I don't know which program is causing this issue.

**UPDATE**: Output of `sudo journalctl --boot` is [here](http://sprunge.us/PcbV).

Comment: have you modified/updated anything lately that is `systemd` related

Comment: @gwillie as far as I remember, I dont know

Comment: `sudo journalctl --boot` might give some clues.

Comment: @meuh output is updated in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is the mysql.service that errors out in you loggs about 10 min after start.

```
Aug 29 18:17:12 flippingbits com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Academic.Zotero[1788]: local variable 'backup_dbFile' referenced before assignment 
Aug 29 18:17:12 flippingbits com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Info.Calculator[1788]: Operation: 
Aug 29 18:22:06 flippingbits systemd[1]: mysql.service start-post operation timed out. Stopping. 
Aug 29 18:22:06 flippingbits systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server. 
Aug 29 18:22:06 flippingbits systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state. 
Aug 29 18:22:06 flippingbits systemd[1]: mysql.service failed.
```

Simplest would probably be to reinstall it.